# Remove duplicates from array and save it to another one

Tags: beginner, c, array, sorting, homework

I have been tasked to make an array without duplicated values from another existing array.
So I did it, but I want to know is there some other better way to do that.

#### Example input/output

`Input`: `1, 15, 1, 5, 1, 3`

`Output`: `1, 15, 5, 3`

#### My code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

  int m[ARRAY_SIZE], p[ARRAY_SIZE];


  for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&m[i]);
  }
  // k variable is used to be the new indexing of the array p;
  int k = 0;

  // if it has a duplication dup is changed to 1;
  int dup = 0;
  
  // Loops through the array.
  for(int i =0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    for(int j = i +1; j <ARRAY_SIZE ; j++) {
        if(m[i] == m[j]) {
            dup = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(dup != 1) {
      p[k++] = m[i];
    }
    dup = 0;
  }

  printf("The array without repeated values\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    printf("%d\n",p[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want some suggestions.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: your algorithm is `O(n^2)` because of the nested loop. You could try using the  `qsort()` function from the C header `stdlib.h` to first sort the array, then iterate through the sorted array once to only add the unique elements. This would be `O(nlogn)` time. Hash sets are even better but I don't know if there's a standard library object for that

Comment: @JohnK Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: You're supposed to ask about *your own* code, not someone else's.

Comment: One of several things is possible: either you copy-and-pasted the original question (including suggestions from its answer), which makes this off-topic due to authorship; or @parallela is a sock puppet for Lubomir Stankov and you're asking the same question with nearly no modification, which makes it a simple duplicate. Either way, in its current state this needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

A flag "dup" can be avoided by rearranging the inner loop. Here is a compact version, somehow a bit inside-out so that we can do our thing `p[k++]=` right on the spot:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; m[i] != m[j]; j++) { /*NO! m[i+1] will be illegal */

            if (j == ARRAY_SIZE) {
                p[k++] = m[i];        // copy this one, next "i" please
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

For clarity I almost prefer this as the inner loop:

```
     for (int j = i + 1;; j++) {

          if (j == ARRAY_SIZE) {
              p[k++] = m[i];        // copy this one, next please
              break;
          }
          if (m[i] == m[j])
              break;               // skip, next 
     }
```

This is more symmetric; you can easily compare the two exit conditions for this eternal loop (no middle expression).

It is important to first check if `j` has reached ARRAY_SIZE, and only then use it in `m[j]`.

---

For an array like `120000000...000012` I think it would be faster to search in the new, unique array...but yes, that is why sorting is a useful first (and main) step.

---

The first (compact) version is even **wrong**. `m[j]` will already be illegal for the last element.

`for (int j = i + 1; m[i] != m[j];...`

Answer (score 1):

If the input really does have commas between the numbers, then we'll want to allow for that here:

> ```
> scanf("%d",&m[i]);
> ```

In any case, it's important to check the return value from `scanf()`, otherwise we could be using values that haven't been properly initialised.

It's probably worth writing separate functions for the input, output and processing, and then have a simple `main()` that links the three together.